# How to make directory writable to myself in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have directory

```
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root  4096 Aug 11 17:05 webapps
```

now I want to allow myself (dims) to write to this directory.

```
bash-3.2$ groups dims
dims : web2 users
```

How to accomplish this? Should I add myself to group "root"? Or may be I should change group ownership to a directory?

I don't want to compromise access and make `dims` root equivalent.

Comment: Just change the ownership of the folder. You shouldn't as yourself to the root group unless you always want root permission.  You can change the group and user of the folder with the respected commands.  You could also simply provide the permission by 777 the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the group owner of the folder to 'wheel' like so:

```
# chgrp wheel -R webapp
```

Then add yourself (dims) to the 'wheel' group like so:

```
# vi /etc/groups`  // (or whichever editor you prefer)
...
`wheel:x:10:root,dims`  //(edit this line. It may defer on your system. just add (dims) to that line
...
```

and save. Make sure the group has write permissions on the folder like so:

```
# chmod g+w -R webapp
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `chmod 777 webapps`

Then every one can read, write and execute – a dangerous way but not for your local directories.

2) `chown dims:dims webapps`

Now this directory is yours, and you can play with it, changing permissions for instance.

Comment: Ok, suppose currently directory is www:www, not root:root. If I change the ownership, I will brake service access to it!

Comment: Ok, use "su -" in redhat base OSs to get root access for your works OR join your userid in www group.

Comment: You could add yourself to the www group.

Comment: Does this depend on whether www is primary or supplementary group?

Comment: `chown dims:www webapps` then `chmod 775 webapps` (or whatever permissions are appropriate in your particular case).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to achieve this is to use [ACL](http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/) (Access Control List), depending on your distribution, this will be enabled by default, if this is not the case, you should follow the instructions on your distribution wiki/help.

Then, once your partition is mounted with ACL option you can use the following to add write permission:

```
setfacl -m u:dims:rwx webapps
setfacl -m d:u:dims:rwx webapps
```